# Почему мы можем использовать пробелы в INSERT INTO а в AUTO_INCREMENT не можем?

Tags: sql, синтаксис

Я новичек. Не понимаю - Почему мы можем позволить использовать пробелы ну например в INSERT INTO а в AUTO_INCREMENT уже не можем?

Comment: Я не понял ваш вопрос. Мы не можем себе разорвать пробелом ни 1 слово, это автоматом становится 2 слова

Comment: ну insert и into 2 слова и auto и increment тоже 2 слова. непонимание возникло в связи с их различным разделением..может потому что insert into это ключевые слова а второе это идентификатор? или я ошибаюсь?

Comment: Потому что так сделали авторы языка

Comment: @Сергей Ваш вопрос звучит так, как будто вместо INSERT INTO можно писать INSERT_INTO или INSERTINTO. SQL изначально был как бы язык близкий к английскому, поэтому и такой синтаксис

Comment: Да, немного неточная формулировка.  Сформулирую - почему мы AUTO_INCREMENT с пробелом не напишем?

Comment: Потому, что `AUTO_INCREMENT` это одно слово. Что бы там не говорили правила естественного языка

Comment: @AntonShchyrov счас как спросит, почему тогда нельзя `AUTOINCREMENT` писать, раз уж одно слово :)

Comment: Очень хочется автору детского вопроса задать в ответ другой детский вопрос, типа а почему белка называется "белкой", хотя она не белая. ИМХО, я бы снес на месте автора вопрос, пока громкий смех не пошел по "интернетам"

Comment: Потому что разработчики MySQL дурачки :) AUTO_INCREMENT не имеет отношения к «стандартному» SQL.

Comment: Как уже написали: потому что так сделали авторы диалекта этого языка. А почему они сделали именно так? Вероятно, потому что парсер для такого варианта сделать существенно проще.

Comment: Имхо, вполне нормальный вопрос. Не над чем тут смеяться.

Comment: @Alexander Petrov вообще-то между вопросом "как оно работает" (это полезный вопрос) и вопросом "почему так назвали" (это в большинстве праздный вопрос, отвлекающий  взрослых от дела) есть глубокая, я бы сказал философская разница :) .

Comment: @andreymal, частенько удачные решения таких «дурачков» становятся впоследствии частью стандартов.

Comment: @MaxU фанатики постгреса мне рассказывали, что это полная хрень и sequence намного круче :D

Answer (score 2):

Я могу сходу назвать две причины, почему я бы сделал также, добавляя свое расширение языка:

1. Проще обрабатывать синтаксис языка когда команды в одно слово (а символ подчеркивания для SQL - обычная буква)
2. Вводя такие идентификаторы можно не бояться, что в будущих версиях стандарта SQL появятся ключевые слова AUTO или INCREMENT и это поломает логику уже написанных запросов.